# Alice answering Bob without knowing the question

Tags: public-key, anonymity, oblivious-transfer

I'm a student and I don't know how to solve the following problem :

- Alice is proposing **a 10 questions list** to Bob.
- Bob choose **only 1 question** and wants to know the answer **without Alice knowing the question**.
- Alice wants that Bob can only have **1 correct answer**.

Is it possible ? If yes how ?

---

In my mind it should begin like this :

1. Bob & Alice knows the 10 questions
2. Alice encrypts each answer with a different key
3. Alice sends the 10 encrypted answers to Bob
4. Bob chose a question (ex : question 2)

*Here comes the intricate part in my mind :*

5. Bob should crypt the question *(How?)*
6. Bob sends the encrypted question to Alice
7. Alice answer to bob with the encrypted decrypting key *(How?)*
8. Bob can decrypt his answer, Alice doesn't know what key she gave

Thanks :)

Comment: I think this might be related to the cryptographic sub-field of [Private Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_information_retrieval), which I do not grasp enough to answer the question well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Oblivious transfer protocol for the answers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer

Here is an example with only 2 answers ($m0$ and $m1$) and uses RSA ($e,d,N$) :

[image]

In your case Alice would have to send $x_0 \ldots x_9$ and Bob would have to pick $b \in \{0,\ldots,9\}$ where $b$ is the number of his question. The operation $m + k$ can be considered as a symmetric encryption of $m$ with the key $k$.

Answer (score 2):

That is possible if and only if [oblivious transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer) is possible.

Proof:
For the left-to-right implication, Alice just lets the last 8 answers be independent of her inputs.

For the right-to-left implication, Alice creates 6 extra answers that are independent of her inputs, splits each answer into 4 [shares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing), and then for i in {0,1,2,3}, obliviously transfers

to Bob the shares of the 8 answers whose i-th bit is the i-th bit of Bob's input.